# Numpy delete submatrix

Tags: python, numpy

I have a numpy array of float. I was wondering if there are any methods or functions to cut/delete a part of matrix.

```
matrix = np.arange(400).reshape(20,20)
```

I considered extracting by indexing the rows/columns by slicing (`Cut(matrix[row_idx,:][:,col_idx])`) or using functions `np.ix`, but that gives me a submatrix, and I need an old matrix without a select part.

The picture below shows what I mean. I want to get a matrix without the column and rows marked in yellow.

[image]

Is there any way to do this? Thank you for your any help.

Comment: You want the old matrix, but the elements in yellow set to `0` or `Nan`?

Comment: I want an old matrix without these elements. As if I truncate the matrix by eg [5: 7] rows and [5: 7] column and my new matrix have a shape (18, 18).

Comment: Or do you want rows and columns removed so you get a new matrix without the marked area? Also, could you provide row/column numbers you want to delete or does it have to be calculated (i.e. five rows in the middle)?

Comment: Yes, that's what I mean. :) Actually, in the further work on the code, these range will be counted, but for now I have to learn a lot and this range will also be given, for example, as you wrote five rows in the middle.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to build a new matrix, you could use `concatenate`:

```
newmatrix = np.concatenate(
    (np.concatenate((matrix[:8,:8], matrix[13:, :8])),
     np.concatenate((matrix[:8,13:], matrix[13:, 13:]))),
    axis=1)
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use np.delete() to delete the columns/rows that you want. This will return a new array

https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.delete.html